# Convert ListView.builder to CupertinoSwitch

Tags: flutter, dart

hi i have code build with ListView.builder for change theme
but the code not good i want change to CupertinoSwitch
example i want CupertinoSwitch to active dark mode and deactivate dark
my code

```
ListView.builder(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              itemCount: AppTheme.values.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final itemAppTheme = AppTheme.values[index];
                return Card(
                  color: appThemeData[itemAppTheme]?.primaryColor ?? Colors.transparent,
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      itemAppTheme.name,
                      style: appThemeData[itemAppTheme]?.textTheme.titleMedium ??
                          Theme
                              .of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .titleMedium,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      context.read<ThemeBloc>().add(ThemeChangedEvent(theme: itemAppTheme));
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
```

my full project : https://github.com/Rabee-Omran/Flutter-Bloc-Library-Tutorial-Theme-App-Dynamic-Theme-Change